# Reading files using getline fstream

Tags: c++, getline

Im having a bit of problem with getline. I want to read line by line but only the >> reading is working while the getline doesnt read. Here is my code:

```
int studentSize;
string programme;
filein >> studentSize;
filein >> programme;
if (programme == "Physics")
{
    for(int i=0; i < studentSize; i++)
    {
        getline (filein,namephys, '*');
        filein >> idphys;
        getline (filein,course, '*');
        filein >> mark;

        phys.push_back(new physics());
        phys[i]->setNameId(namephys, idphys);
        phys[i]->addCourse(course, mark);
        sRecord[idphys] = phys[i];
    }
}
```

And here is my file:

```
2
Physics
Mark Dale* 
7961050 
Quantum Programming* 
99
```

The output for Mark Dale and Quantum Programming doesnt work well. It seems to be getting the whole line before them. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're not consuming each line to the end for any value you're slurping with `>>`. Ex:. `idphys` will be read, but the line is still current. `getline` will pull everything (including the immediate newline) until it hits your terminal `*`.

Comment: How should I do it then? Because I was thinking of using getline for the idphys part too, but it cant be done since its an int. I tried using file.ignore() after >> but it doesnt work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stream might fail at any time & your loop has no way of reacting to it.
You should do something like this :

```
if( programme == "Physics" )
{
    filein.ignore();

    // a more strict version is : (#include <limits>)
    //filein.ignore( numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n' );

    while( getline(filein, namephys, '*') &&
           filein >> idphys &&
           filein.ignore() && //** ignore the trailing newline (operator>> doesn't read it)
           getline(filein, course, '*') &&
           filein >> mark &&
           filein.ignore() )
    {
        /* do something */
    }
}
```

This loop immediately exits whenever the stream state becomes bad

Comment: Works perfectly to solve the trailing newline. Thanks!

Comment: Your `filein.ignore()` is considerably more strict than the commented version. It requires the *next* char in the input stream be the newline, otherwise the newline (and everything between it and the ignored single char) is left on the stream. For hardening the input to be precisely as shown without whitespace between the end of tokens and the newline, you can't get tighter. It would be more *forgiving* if you used the commented version. And +1 btw. nice answer.